# How to create a folder on a server in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, scp

I am writing a script to upload a folder from client to server using the module `net/scp` but I don't know to to create a new folder automatically with ruby if it doesn't already exist on the server. How can I do it? And how can I run any Ruby script on the server using `net/scp`?

This is the code I have so far:

```
def upload(fileName_upload,pathLocalFolder,pathRemoteFolder)
  pathLocalFolder=pathLocalFolder + '/'+fileName_upload
  Net::SCP.start($host, $username, :password => $pass_Word) do |scp|
  scp.upload! pathLocalFolder, pathRemoteFolder
  channel = scp.upload(pathLocalFolder, pathRemoteFolder)
  channel.wait
end

def uploadFolder(pathLocalFolder,nameFolderInServer)
  # I want to create a folder on the server, but I don't know how to do it
  #Dir.mkdir(nameFolderInServer) unless File.exists?(nameFolderInServer)
  Dir.glob(pathLocalFolder) do |item|
    name=File.basename item,''
    if File.directory?(name)
      uploadFolder(pathLocalFolder+'/'+name,name)
    end
    if File.file?(name)
      upload(name,pathLocalFolder,$remote_Path+'/'+nameFolderInServer)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Thank you for improving your question--it's great that you care!  This question is really two questions; I found an existing question that answers one of them, so I've linked this question to that one.  Your other question (about net/scp) should be asked separately, if it is not already answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileUtils.mkdir_p](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p). There's no need to check if it exists already, as this method will do nothing if it the given directory already exists.